# Render image before uploading it in Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I'm building a Shiny app that lets users upload images to the server. I'd like to display the image on the screen without having to upload it first and then get the rendered output back. Is this possible?

This is my code right now. You can select an image file, which gets uploaded. The image is then rendered from the file on the server side, after it's been received. I'd like to avoid the roundtrip.

**UI**

```
fluidPage(
    titlePanel("File upload"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("img", "Choose image file",
                accept=c("image/jpeg", "image/x-windows-bmp"))
        ),
        mainPanel(
            imageOutput("picture", width="500px", height="500px")
        )
    )
)
```

**Server**

```
function(input, output, session)
{
    output$picture <- renderImage({
        imgFile <- input$img
        if(is.null(imgFile))
            return(list(src=""))
        list(src=imgFile$datapath, alt=imgFile$name, contentType=imgFile$type)
    }, deleteFile=FALSE)

    # do more stuff with the file
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. The file is on the computer of your user and not on your server and you want to display it without uploading? Is there an upload option outside shiny and you know the path?

Comment: I want to upload the file, but I also want to display it without waiting for the server to get back to me. I do some backend computing which can take some time, so it would be good to be able to display the image straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** 
Okay, I now the question is clear for me, I hope :). 
The problem is that pictures are added within `<output id="list"></output>`. So I would suggest clearing it before a new picture is added with: `document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = ''`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("File upload"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("img", "Choose image file",
                accept=c("image/jpeg", "image/x-windows-bmp"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      HTML('<output id="list"></output>')
    )
  )), 
  server = function(input, output, session){ 
    shinyjs::runjs("

                   function handleFileSelect(evt) {
                   document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = ''
                   var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
                   // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
                   for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

                   // Only process image files.
                   if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                   continue;
                   }

                   var reader = new FileReader();

                   // Closure to capture the file information.
                   reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                   return function(e) {
                   // Render thumbnail.
                   var span = document.createElement('span');
                   span.innerHTML = ['<img class=\"thumb\" src=\"', e.target.result,
                   '\" title=\"', escape(theFile.name), '\"/>'].join('');
                   document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                   };
                   })(f);

                   // Read in the image file as a data URL.
                   reader.readAsDataURL(f);
                   }
                   }
                   document.getElementById('img').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);")

  })
```

Comment: Btw, to fix the problem with files appearing twice, remove the `renderImage`/`imageOutput` bits.

Comment: I am confused. When I run the code provided above and upload multiple times I see no pictures in the sidebar and one picture in the main panel, namely the one I uploaded last (in Firefox and Chrome).....

Comment: What's happening is that your Javascript isn't producing any output at all. The picture that gets displayed is from the `renderImage` call, not the JS code.

Comment: You can see this by inserting a `Sys.sleep(2)` somewhere inside the server code, or by changing the dimensions of the image created by the JS. The former will delay the rendering of the image, and the latter will have no effect.

Comment: I get it, I removed the double display it was a bit confusing. I think my new edit should help.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use package `shinyjs` to call `FileReader` from HTML 5 [read here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

```
library(shinyjs)
shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("File upload"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("img", "Choose image file",
                accept=c("image/jpeg", "image/x-windows-bmp")),
      HTML('<output id="list"></output>')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      imageOutput("picture", width="500px", height="500px")
    )
  )), 
server = function(input, output, session){ 
  shinyjs::runjs("

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
   var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
   // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
   for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

   // Only process image files.
   if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
   continue;
   }

   var reader = new FileReader();

   // Closure to capture the file information.
   reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
   return function(e) {
   // Render thumbnail.
   var span = document.createElement('span');
   span.innerHTML = ['<img class=\"thumb\" src=\"', e.target.result,
   '\" title=\"', escape(theFile.name), '\"/>'].join('');
   document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
   };
   })(f);

   // Read in the image file as a data URL.
   reader.readAsDataURL(f);
   }
   }
   document.getElementById('img').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);")

  output$picture <- renderImage({
    imgFile <- input$img
    if(is.null(imgFile))
      return(list(src=""))
    list(src=imgFile$datapath, alt=imgFile$name, contentType=imgFile$type)
    }, deleteFile=FALSE)
})
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, but I'm running into a couple of problems. First, the picture generated by the JS appears in the sidebar, where I want it to replace the picture in the main panel. Also, if I use the upload control more than once the sidebar picture doesn't get erased. Instead each new picture is displayed below the one from before.

Comment: I can fix the first problem by putting the `HTML()` element in the main panel, but I'm not sure how to fix the second.